# Javascript and cookies are enabled, but they still aren't? Meta refresh?

Tags: java, javascript, cookies, htmlunit

I am trying to make a web scraper using my university's website.

I am having trouble even loading the sign-in page because it says I do not have javascript and cookies enabled when I believe I do.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

// Sign In Page
final HtmlPage signInPage = webClient.getPage("https://eraider.ttu.edu/");

System.out.println(signInPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
```

I am receiving the following message:

> This web site requires that JavaScript and Cookies be enabled in your web browser.  We were unable to determine if your browser has these features enabled because META REFRESH failed.  You need to make sure META REFRESH is enabled in your browser's security settings.  If you need assistance, contact the TTU IT Help Desk at 806-742-HELP (4357).

I was not able to figure out what meta refresh is.

Update: I tried adding:

```
new WaitingRefreshHandler().handleRefresh(signInPage, new URL("https://eraider.ttu.edu/"), 10);
```

but only received this before receiving the same result as before:

```
Aug 24, 2014 9:28:54 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Aug 24, 2014 9:28:55 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Aug 24, 2014 9:29:05 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
```

---

#### Solved

When using HtmlUnit, use WaitingRefreshHandler and make sure you wait until the page is fully loaded. When using Selenium Webdriver, see below:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://raiderlink.ttu.edu");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name(elementName)));
```

Comment: It's a forced reload of a document in a webbrowser via a [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)-tag.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What would I need to change so that it does not fail?

Comment: I'm not familiar with java/htmlunit but maybe this will be a start:[`refreshHandler`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/RefreshHandler.html)